# How to Get QTextEdit Text & ScrollBar Size?

Tags: qt

I use windows 8.1 64bit and linux 64bit, I am using Qt Version 5.4.

The text is written in QTextEdit and you can resize this TextEdit widget.

When you resize the TextEdit widget while text is being written, a scrollbar is automatically created when the size is reduced.

I want to know the minimum size of the text in the TextEdit Widget without scrollbars, and I can't make the widget smaller than its size.

How can I find the minimum size without scrollbars?

Example 1)

```
ab
c
```

When written as above, the screen

```
ab
c
```

This is the minimum size at which no scrollbars appear.

Example 2)

```
abc
```

When I wrote as above, on a screen

```
abc
```

This is the minimum size at which no scrollbars appear.

The text you enter is all formatted text.

As soon as the letter size and color were applied.

ab is font size 20
c can be font size 25.

Comment: 1) You should not provide an email since no one will send you an email. 2) Show what you have tried even if it does not work since OS is not a SW write service.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) and [QFontMetricsF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html).